# Custom Alert Dialog does not dismiss

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am creating a custom `AlertDialog` to show loading on button click event listener. The Alert dialog `show()` function works fine but the `dismiss()` function is not working

```
 public AlertDialog LoadDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_show_loading, null));
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        dialog = builder.create();

        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        return dialog;
    }
```

To show loading on button click on different class, I just call:

```
new LoadingDialog(context).LoadDialog().show(); //works fine
```

and dismiss loading I call:

```
new LoadingDialog(context).LoadDialog().dismiss(); // does not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the returned *dialog* into a variable otherwise all you are doing is creating a new `AlertDialog` instance and calling `show()` and then another new instance and calling `dismiss()` (hence the one never dissappears):

```
AlertDialog dialog = new LoadingDialog(context).LoadDialog();
```

Then you can call:

```
dialog.show();
```

Or

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no dismiss function AlertDialog.Builder Class.
Instead use,

```
AlertDialog dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

and call

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you‘re calling `dismiss` on a different instance than the one created by the first call to `show`, as the `LoadingDialog` method creates a new instance on every call.

You need to store the instance created by `show` and call `dismiss` on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `new LoadingDialog(context).LoadDialog().dismiss(); // does not work` this will create a new dialog box reference and tries to dismiss it instead of using the same dialogue you have created before.

You need to store the created dialogue with this one -

`new LoadingDialog(context).LoadDialog().show(); //works fine`

and then use `.dismiss` on that stored variable